# Rails: Flash messages doesn't clear until it is read/accessed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, flash-message

I set the flash message as below in one of my routes

```
def signup
   flash[:is_signup] = true
   ... redirect_to route1 : route2  // based on some logic, redirect accordingly
end

def route1
    // access flash[:is_signup]
    flash.discard(:is_signup)
    // do something 
end
```

As depicted above, after i set the flash variable, i could redirect_to either the route(route1) that uses this flash variable or another route(route2) that doesn't care about this flash variable at all.

The issue is, when i `redirect to route2`, and then go on and mind my own business, hitting several routes/actions in the process, when i end up hitting the `route1`, the flash variable is still there.

I haven't seen anything in the documentation that says it is available until it is read. Is this the case? or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: not sure I understand as the `Flash` object should be cleared after either action `route1` or `route2` renders. Are you sure you are not reassigning it somewhere possibly? Or that your `route1` view is actually setting this rather than accessing the flash itself?

Comment: additionally you may misunderstand what `FlashHash#discard` actually does. It does not "delete" this message but rather marks it to be discarded at the end of this action. If this action renders instead of  redirecting ("make another request") that value will still exist until the next request is made.

Comment: Hey @engineersmnky
I am positive that i am not re-assigning it anywhere. Also, in route1, i am using flash[:key] on the RHS, so no question of assigning it there.
Yep, Got the discard thing right on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this as well (rails 4.2.11), and agree: no docs indicate access of flash should be necessary.

But, if I have a page that sets `flash[:blah] = 'applesauce'` and consumes the flash (e.g., `puts flash[:blah]`) on the next request, that key is not present in the following request.  If I don't, it will linger through request after request until I hit a one where I check the flash.

My workaround is this:
In application_controller.rb

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :touch_flash
#...
  def touch_flash
    flash
  end
end
```

This act of referencing flash appears to be enough to trigger a discard at end of the request (but doesn't interfere with any actual access later in the request).  Next request, it's gone as expected.